# Samsung apps and Google AdMob

Tags: android, admob, samsung-mobile

I want to publish an app on Samsung Apps, my app has an AdMob banner. Will Samsung apps have an issue with the fact the app has AdMob ads? I can't find a conclusive answer on Google, can someone answer from experience?

I know this isn't a programming question but it is a development question so I will appreciate if you would allow it.

Comment: Samsung does not allow any other ad provider and SDK than their own in-house solution: http://www.samsungadhub.com/

Answer (score 1):

According to the current official [Terms and Conditions](http://seller.samsungapps.com/help/termsAndConditions.as?channel=mobile) of the Samsung Apps Seller Office third party advertising is allowed under the following conditions:

> **16.4** You may include third party advertisement within Applications, which shall be subject to the then applicable Samsung advertising
>   guidelines. Samsung reserves the right to reject or remove advertising
>   that Samsung deems contrary to its advertising guidelines. These
>   guidelines are subject to change at any time and Samsung may waive any
>   of these guidelines at its discretion. Any revenues to be generated by
>   such third party advertisement within Applications shall not be
>   counted as the "Sales Proceeds" subject to revenue sharing between
>   Samsung and you under clause 6 and, therefore, you are entitled to
>   retain all revenues from such third party advertisement.

They are referring to the "Samsung advertising guidelines" which cannot be found anywhere (except for the TV part of Samsung Apps which is in contrast to the mobile part as it has its own Terms and Conditions). Thus no other restrictions than the ones mentioned earlier need to be applied in my opinion.